# Android NOT autoComplete or spinner

Tags: android, android-widget

I have related input text fields in my android application.

The user first enters a parent value (using autocomplete text)

for the related child text entry i have tried a spinner and autocomplete text.

the spinner shows existing values, which is a good start, however i need the user to be able to enter new values as well. Once the user adds a new value this will be incorporated in the drop down list on subsequent views of the screen.

the user may not know all available values so autocomplete doesnt satisfy my requirements as you have to know what is already in the list for it to assist you.

i feel spinner is the best starting point for my child text entry field.

How do i enable text entry into a spinner?

whats the "Best" solution for this problem?